# Sencha list Item tap issue views gets added twice

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am facing problem while adding new view on list item tap.
When I single Tap on list item view gets added twice.
Issue is I have to click back button twice to come back on the same page.
Anybody knows what is exact issue.